# applying images to a dynamic data listbox in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm new to xaml and wpf. I actually wanted to create a dynamic listbox populating a list of customers with images ('redball' for old customers and 'greenball' for new customers) adjacent to the names in the list. The list as I mentioned will be having random number of entries. Kindly suggest me or guide me trough any samples or blogs which might be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if your customer object has a public property (IsNew or something like that) then you can simply use a datatemplate with Style.Datatrigger to show a green or red ball. if you a new to wpf you should read some books to bwecome familiar with bindings, xaml styles and so on. and if you did this you should read about mvvm pattern.

Comment: I have gone through the basics of wpf and i was able to populate a single image to a single value manually. But the case I am talking about here is that i need to assign images to a collection in a listbox which I am pulling from the database.